# Handling promises with fetch() in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch, es6-promise

I'm creating my first MERN stack application, and trying to implement a simple API that calls my express server from my React front-end components. I have the API working on the back end, and it is sending the data correctly through `fetch()`, but I'm having trouble resolving the promise from `fetch()` in my React component, with the call not stopping firing. My code looks as follows (assuming as of right now all API calls return a dummy format like `{ title: 'foo', ... }`:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';

const getApiData = async (route) => {
  try {
    let apiData = await fetch(route);
    let apiDataJson = await apiData.json();
    return apiDataJson;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error('Error on fetch', {
      error: err
    })
  }
}

var retrieve_data = async (route, setterCallback) => {
  await getApiData(`/api/${route}`).then((data) => {
    console.log('Data retrieved from API')
    setterCallback(<div>{data.title}</div>)
  }).catch(() => {
    setterCallback(<div>ERROR</div>)
  })
}

const MyComponent = () => {

  const [innerDiv, setinnerDiv] = useState(0);

  let data = retrieve_data('myEndpoint', setinnerDiv);

  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Data Retrieved in MyComponent:</h1>
      {innerDiv}
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I compile the above the component successfully renders (i.e. `<MyComponent />` looks like:

```
<div>
    <h1>Data Retrieved in MyComponent:</h1>
    <div>foo</div>
</div>
```

However, then `then` block keeps executing (i.e. the `'Data retrieved from API'` logs to the console hundreds of times/second until I close the application. How can I stop this from executing once it has set the component? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `useEffect` to stop the component from re-rendering. Try something like this.

```js
const MyComponent = () => {

  const [innerDiv, setinnerDiv] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    retrieve_data('myEndpoint', setinnerDiv);
  }, []);

  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Data Retrieved in MyComponent:</h1>
      {innerDiv}
    </div>
  );
}
```